# using libraries generated with gcc with msvc toolset

Tags: visual-c++, mingw, gtkmm

after painfull strugling for days, I somehow managed to build latest gtkmm 3.10 libraries under windows with MinGW tools.
The output generated has gcc extensions, ie.(*.a *.dll.a *.la)
this all works fine, I'm using code::blocks with MinGW to link to the libraries, but I wonder if it is possible to link those libraires with MSVC++-12.0 toolset withing visual studio 2013?
so I don't have to use gnu tools any more then.
if yes, then how should this be done? thank you.

Comment: Rebuilding the necessary libraries [using MSVC++](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gtkmm/MSWindows/BuildingGtkmm#Using_MSVC.2B-.2B-) isn't a solution for you?

Comment: I've reading this link(building with MSVC is real pain), it's not as easy as using mingw. one needs to adjust headers every now and then, I'm not knoweleged so much, so I'm looking for simple solution if possible, thanks.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune also btw, the link you posted is describing how to build with MSVC-10.0 it does not work with MSVC-12.0 :) (at least not in an easy way)

Comment: I'm not aware of any solution to convert MinGW libs to MSVC unfortunately. There is a link on that page to a Github site supplying Cmake files, so you might try installing Cmake and generating an MSVC project that you can use. Other than that, I haven't the foggiest idea how to help, except perhaps exporting the CC and CXX environment variables to "cl.exe" and adding the BIN directory containing that executable to your PATH environment variable before executing the configure script... I've never done it, but it may work. I wish you luck. Do the installers not work for your MSVC version?

Comment: I understand. Sorry, but I'm not familiar with MSVC very much, and I have older versions anyway. I didn't realize the IDE changed so radically between versions, assuming that is what you're talking about.

Comment: provided gtkmm instalers are fine but they are built with older MSVC version which means old gtkmm and no C++11 in VS :/ so building own stuff is "must", thank you for your input about adding msvc enviroinment to msys, it's worth trying out (until first build error if any) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware, gtkmm is a c++ library, and c++ does *not* have a stable abi(application binary interface).  This means that static libraries compiled under different versions of the same compiler *may not work*.  This is why its recommended to recompile c++ libraries for your c++ app/lib so everything has the same compiler building it.

If you're building your app in VS2012, you need to compile gtkmm with the version of  VS2012 that you'll use.

But not all is lost forever!  Herb Sutter has put forward creating a stable abi.  https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n4028.pdf

Comment: it looks I'm facing exactly this right now as I'm now able to build a sample app after successful gtkmm build :/ thank you.

Answer (score 0):

it's me again, not that I'm answering my own question but I would like to put some additional information for those people who read this Q/A.

As I told I built my own gtkmm libraries and the problem with not being able to build the libraries was in code::blocks, at this point code:blocks make me struggle for so many hours before figuring out that solution to build your gtkmm application is to remove code::block and compile manualy instead on commandline using your own manualy typed compile flags.
Reason is that code::block didn't properly save my seetings so I had undefined references.